# e4 RCP how to programmatically edit main menu

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I would like to modify main menu items in my code, not in e4xmi. How can I do this?

I have two "handled menu item" type "radio" in Main menu (no in part menu). I want to check which is active. I also want to programmatically change active item.

Comment: This is very unclear. Please [edit] your question and be much more specific about what you want to do.

Comment: I tried my best. I hope that now is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MMenuItem` represents a menu item. It has `isSelected()` and `setSelection(boolean)` methods for testing and setting the menu item selection.

You can find a `MMenuItem` using the model service:

```
@Inject
EModelService modelService;

@Inject
MApplication app;

List<MMenuItem> menuList = modelService.findElements(app, "menu item id", MMenuItem.class, null, EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU);

MMenuItem menuItem = menuList.get(0);
```

In handlers you can just inject the current `MMenuItem` directly in the `@Execute` method.